# How to change the perspective of an image

Tags: java, image-processing

Actually I am working on a application where I need to change the flooring of a room. The application's back end is in java.Suppose this is the room.

[Room whose floor needs to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlvPr.jpg)

[Room after floor removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvMkL.jpg)

[Carpet which needs to be laid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtnB9.jpg)

[Result after executing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86Yl.jpg)

I have removed the floor of the room using software like photoshop. Now I need to add new carpet floor to that image. The carpet flooring must be dynamic where a user selects any carpet and the images replaces after rendering.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FloorChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 1920; // width of the image
        int height = 1080; // height of the image

        // For storing image in RAM
        BufferedImage image = null;
        BufferedImage background = null;
        BufferedImage finalImage = null;

        // READ IMAGE
        try {
            File input_file = new File("room.png"); // image file path
            File floor_tile = new File("milkyway.jpg"); // image file path

            FloorChange floorChange = new FloorChange();
            image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            background = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            finalImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


            System.out.println("Reading complete.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        try {
            Graphics2D g = finalImage.createGraphics();

            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            File output_file = new File("floor1.png");

            ImageIO.write(finalImage, "png", output_file);
            System.out.println("Writing complete.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type) {
        int IMG_WIDTH = 1920;
        int IMG_CLAHEIGHT = 1080;
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CLAHEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CLAHEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }

I have replaced the floor but the image was stretched and if I repeat the image it gives lines between each carpet. And also the perspective of the imag e is not proper.
```

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: I think perhaps `TexturePaint` can be used to create a repeating pattern of the carpet, along with an `AffineTransform` that creates the (fake) perspective.